# how do you convert this syslog-ng cfg to rsyslog?

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng, rsyslog

How do I convert the following to rsyslog syntax?

> ```
> filter local2 { facility(local2); }; 
> filter not_local2 { not facility(local2); }; 
>
> destination server2  { tcp("server2" port(1111)); };
> destination localhost { file ("/var/log/local2.log"); };
>
> log { source(s_all); filter(local2); destination(localhost); };
>
> filter pics { program ("preview_*"); };
> destination pics  { file ("/logdir/${PROGRAM}.log"); };
> log { source(s_all); filter(pics); destination(pics); };
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Did you find it ? If not, propably it's something like ...

if (%facility% equals local2 ) then /var/log/local2.log

if (%programname% equals 'preview_*' ) then /logdir/%programname%.log

(You didn't use server2 anywhere, so i didn't include it)

(Much easier ;p)

Hope it helps.